# Keep same \vfill over different pages

Tags: multicol, exam, fill, vspace

I'm using `\vspace{\fill}` to even space out questions of an exam, but the length changes from page to page. I want the same space after every question, and the last question to be at the end of the last page (but for that question to have the same `\fill` space after it). I'm using multicol too, so I'd like the last column to not be empty.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem, multicol}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{questions}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}

\end{questions}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to align the questions, use a 1 2// 3 4// 5 6 scheme using paracol.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but unless every question occupies exactly the same amount of space, what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: I'm not interested in the alignment of the questions. I'm just trying to add the same amount of `\vspace` after every question so I don't have empty space at the end.    

To illustrate, lets say if I didn't have any space after the questions, I was left with 20cm of space after question 20. Therefore I want to put 1cm of space after every question so that Question 20 only has the 1 cm of space after it. Of course this has to be done automatically because the lengths of the questions aren't known beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the same trick as multicols only over two pages instead of one.  That is, it divides the text into 4 roughly equal columns BEFORE expanding `\vfill`.  The problem is the columns are not precisely equal, nor are the number of `\vfill`s per column equal.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem, multicol}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\global\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{\begin{questions}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\question This text means nothing. 
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
\end{oneparchoices}
\vspace{\fill}
\end{questions}}% end of \vbox
\setbox0=\vsplit\tempbox to 0.25\ht\tempbox
\setbox1=\vsplit\tempbox to 0.333\ht\tempbox
\setbox2=\vsplit\tempbox to 0.5\ht\tempbox
\unvbox0\columnbreak
\unvbox1\columnbreak
\unvbox2\columnbreak
\unvbox\tempbox
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you explain what's going on in your code? Especially after the end of \vbox.

Comment: \vsplit splits off part of a \vbox into another \vbox with a given height (not counting glue). Each time the original \vbox gets smaller.  (This is how TeX splits paragraphs at the end of pages.)

Answer (score 1):

(1) To avoid having an empty last column of the second page use `\begin {multicols}{2}` instead of `\begin {multicols*}{2}`. There will be two balanced columns instead of a single column.

(2) To avoid having to insert the `\vspace{...}` after each question, the `oneparchoices` environment was modified to automatically include it at the end.

(3) Instead of using `\vspace {\fill}`, which distributes the space evenly within a page, but can vary from page to page,  it's best to use a fixed length but with some glue added, to help LaTeX's page breaking mechanism to avoid, when possible, breaks between the question and the answers.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem, multicol}

%% ************************  added <<<
\AtEndEnvironment{oneparchoices}{%
%\vspace{0ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex} % 16 questions en the first page   
%\vspace{0.8ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}% 15 questions but ..
\vspace{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex} % 14 questions
%\vspace{3ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}  %13 questions
}
%% *************************

\begin{document}
    
\large
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{questions}

            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question  This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question  This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing.
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question  This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. This text means nothing. 
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    
            \question  This text means nothing. % last question
            \begin{oneparchoices}
                \choice 1 \choice 2 \choice 3 \choice 4
            \end{oneparchoices}
    %   \vspace*{\fill}  %<<<< uncomment for two columns, but not exactly balanced
        \end{questions} 

    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

If you do not like the spacing in last page, put `\vspace*{\fill}` before `\end{questions}` for two slightly unbalanced columns.

[image: c]

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply, the comments are really useful for someone like me! I've edited my document to use the `\AtEndEnvironment` command, (I had to import etoolbox). Spacing-wise, my main goal is to add `\vspace{X}` after everyone question so that there is little to no space left after Question 20's space. Since I don't know how long the questions are beforehand, I need `X` to be defined (and constant throughout the document) automatically. That's why I was using `multicols*`.

Comment: Of course you can use    `\multicols*`  instead. Modifying the environment adds always same space,  without the need to write `\vspace` every time. And  is much easier if you want to modify the  space between questions.